# How to gps data anomaly detection in python

Tags: machine-learning, python, algorithms, anomaly-detection, outlier

I have gps format dataset lat, lon. I want to detection anomaly using python.

I tested **knn**, **smv**, **cof**, **iforest** using pycaret. But i did not.

These colors anomlay because the

- angle change is too much
- the changes of the points are deviated too much to the right and left
- distance more two points between

but since the other colors go in a row, they are not anomaly because the heading values are reasonable.

also i grouped according to *sequnceUUID*

```
heading(bearing) is angle of north.
```

[image: My dataset image]

I want to detect and extract purple, green and brown datasets that are out of the way.

[my dataset geojson format](https://controlc.com/c8e6cfe5)

Answer (score 0):

GPS data includes positional and time data. If the n+1 position at t+1 is too far away from the n position at t (i.e. d>0.5m for instance), you should be able to detect an anomaly.

Same topic about the angle: if the angle between d1 and d2 is grater than a normal value (ex: 2 degree) then it should be considered as an anomaly.

You should consider the number of abnormal values in a row: if there are more than 3 for example, you should consider them as an anomaly.

Comment: I understand and will try.